# curl requests to JIRA log in as anonymous user even w/ valid credentials

Tags: python, html, json, rest, jira

So I fixed my original problem (see below). However my current issue is that I am logged in as an anonymous user (even though giving the site valid and previously used on-site credentials).

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorizatio: Basic (rand letters)lashdglsglhasdglasdg==" -H        
"Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.company-
some.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=QA (this project does exist, I verified)
```

The problem is that now it is returning this as an answer...

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 15 Jun 2015 20:39:44 GMT
X-AREQUESTID: 978x78980x1
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=S2XZ-384H-UGNQ-    
RCZ3|6f58fa3340fe45a4360ae177afe49b0e69facda2|lout; Path=/; Secure
X-AUSERNAME: anonymous
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"errorMessages":["The value 'QA' does not exist for the field 
'project'."],"errors":{}}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Bump? Seriously, there is no information that I can find. Help would be AWESOME

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869954/get-curl-call-not-returning-json-object/30870264?noredirect=1#comment49781982_30870264  

In addition to the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use **"basic authentication"**, make sure that the combination of username:password is base 64 encrypted. Below is an example in Groovy:

```
    Base64.encodeBase64String(("${username}:${password}").getBytes())
```

JIRA REST API returns response in JSON format.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that with the correct user:pass encoded and it is still returning an 'AUTHENTICATED_FAILED'. Also thank you for the information about the JSON return value.

Comment: It took me a while to figure this out and there were no example out there to rely on. I ended up writing this blog, which is good for Grails/Groovy. Hope it helps: http://ashahrami.blogspot.ca/2014/12/jira-rest-client-implementation-in.html

Comment: I also noticed you don't have **Authorization: Basic** in your request header. Look into the blog address for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am using python for this particular project. Also, the problem I had with the blog was that it was not a GET request. I got the POST request to work on a trial basis. However, my main problem is still that it will not authenticate despite the correct encoded or decoded username and password. Thank you though

Comment: Finally got in. Needed to encode the whole string not just "xxx:xxx" but also the colon "xxx(x=:)xxx". My problem now is just that I am logged in as an anonymous user, which is causing problems with retrieving what it is that I want.

Comment: That's great! You probably can fix that in JIRA. Make sure you have proper account setting in JIRA. Btw. in my code snippet I had the colon included :)