# GET curl call not returning JSON object

Tags: python, json, curl

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic --------------------=" -H     
"Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.-----------.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=assignee=wwilson
```

This returns actual correct output, but when I try to pipe a command to format it it tells me that no JSON object could be decoded.

```
{"expand":"names,schema","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":1,"issues":
[{"expand":"editmeta,renderedFields,transitions,changelog,operations","id":"11497"    
,"self":"https://jira.some-company.net/rest/api/latest/issue/11497","key":"QA-
121","fields":{"summary":"Test_Run","progress":
.... Not going to give you the crapton of lines in the middle ....
{"progress":0,"total":0},"lastViewed":"2015-06-16T09:52:41.616-
0400","components":
[],"timeoriginalestimate":null,"aggregatetimespent":null}}]}
```

This is what the output currently looks like (partial example, JSON is correct, but has sensitive information and -> ), but it has another 40 lines or so. Pretty print would be the goal. I tried it by piping in...

```
| python -m json.tool
```

But again it threw even though it is a valid JSON:

```
No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Your JSON is incomplete, is it returned that way?

Comment: No, it's just an example. My bad should have specified. Some of the JSON's are 1000's of lines long @Klaus

Comment: The problem is that your JSON is faulty because it's not complete. It would be good if you could post the full JSON output.

Comment: Did you test it with a shorter JSON that can be easily validated?

Comment: Is that your real password in the Basic auth? If so you should change it

Comment: No, I changed it @John

Comment: @klaus I did test it, it works as a JSON. Just not being returned as a JSON object for some reason.

Comment: Also for future reference, if anyone is ever looking at this. '-D-' piped the output to stdout as opposed to returning the file. It redirected it. When you take -D- away it just returns the object with nothing done to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-D-` is including the headers in stdout. You should leave that off

The `-D` option dumps the headers to the given file.
The special filename `-` is stdout

Comment: Thank you! Worked beautifully @John What does the -D- stand for?

Comment: @Ian it's the short form for `--dump-header`